# Line integral does not dependent on parametrization

Tags: integration, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and a curve $\Gamma\subset M$ with $C^1$parametrizations $\gamma:[a, b]\to M$ and $\tilde{\gamma}:[c, d]\to M$. If $\omega$ is a $1$-form on $M$, prove that:
>
> $$\int_a^b \gamma^*\omega = \int_c^d \tilde{\gamma}^*\omega$$

My intial idea was to claim that there exists an increasing diffeomorphism $\phi:[a,b]\to[c, d]$ (therefore, orientation preserving) such that $\gamma=\tilde{\gamma}\circ\phi$. And therefore:

$$\int_{[c,d]} \tilde{\gamma}^*{\omega}=\int_{\phi^{-1}([c,d])} \phi^*\circ\tilde{\gamma}^*(\omega)=\int_{[a,b]} (\tilde{\gamma}\circ\phi)^*(\omega)=\int_{[a,b]} \gamma^*\omega$$

However, I'm not sure that such a diffeomorphism always exists, since we only know that $\gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}$ are $C^1$, so I'm stuck with this argumentation. Any sugestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can show that any homeomorphism of between interval is monotonic. Suppose you have $x<y$ and $f(x) > f(y)$. Consider the interval $I = (f(y),f(x))$. Then $f^{-1}(I) = (y,x)$. However $x<y$, so this is a contradiction.

Comment: Maybe you should make explicit that you are using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Since the OP is probably in differential topology, I am just using the fact that continuous image of connected set is connected.

Comment: Fair enough, IVT is just a rewording.

Comment: but can we guarantee that there exists a $\phi$ such that $\gamma=\tilde{\gamma}\circ\phi$?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.